# Step Progress with thumb icon on top of step

Tags: android, android-progressbar, seekbar

Any library to design this step progress bar or seek bar? [Screenshot.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bos9g.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try 6 & 7 from this link, These library can be customised to get your design, Or alternatively, You can also make your own seek bar by extending android seek bar with custom rendering of your stepped icon/label on to canvas:

[Top 15 Seekbar and Slider Github UI Libraries and Components](https://uxplanet.org/top-15-seekbar-and-slider-github-ui-libraries-and-components-java-swift-kotlin-d0f6a9658be3)